# How to export railway stations from specific country including their name, lattitude and longitude from OpenRailwayMap.org?

Tags: openstreetmap

I need to export railway stations from specific country including their name, lattitude and longitude from OpenRailwayMap.org?
I didn't find any information about exporting data at official site or any other sources.
Or maybe there are exists any other sources.

Comment: OpenRailwayMap uses data from OpenStreetMap. So you have to obtain this data from OSM.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to extract using OSM?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How to extract certain data from OSM is explained in various places. Overpass API (or overpass turbo, a web frontend) are a good start. Try searching for the `railway=station` tag.